# Implementing the use of a random pivot instead of choosing the first element as pivot in QuickSort, java

Tags: java, quicksort

So here is the source code for my project. The `"cmp(i,j)"` function returns a negative value if `i < j`, a positive value if `i > j`, and `0` if `i = j`.

As you can see, I choose the current first element of the list as pivot, which works. Now I want to use a random pivot. If I just do a "`int pivot = first + random.nextInt(last-first+1);"` I get a ton of error on runtime.

Source code:

```
    public void sort(){ 
        sortQuick(0, getElementCount()-1);
    }
    public void sortQuick (int first, int last){
    // pivot tilldelas ett värde mellan noll och antal element i vektorn.
    //final Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println(("Last: " + last + ", first : " + first));
    //int pivot = first + random.nextInt(last-first+1);
    int pivot = first;
    System.out.println(pivot);
    int up = first;                          // index of left-to-right scan
    int down = last;                            // index of right-to-left scan

    if (last - first >= 1){               // check that there are at least two elements to sort

        // set the pivot as the first element in the partition

        while (down > up)  {                 // while the scan indices from left and right have not met,

            while (cmp(up,pivot) <= 0 && up <= last && down > up)  // from the left, look for the first
                up++;                                    // element greater than the pivot
            while (cmp(down,pivot) > 0 && down >= first && down >= up) // from the right, look for the first
                down--;                                     // element not greater than the pivot
            if (down > up){                                   // if the left seekindex is still smaller than
                swap(up, down);
            }
            // the right index, swap the corresponding elements
        }
        swap(first, down);          // after the indices have crossed, swap the last element in
                                    // the left partition with the pivot 
        sortQuick(first, down - 1); // quicksort the left partition
        sortQuick(down + 1, last);   // quicksort the right partition
    }
    else    // if there is only one element in the partition, do not do any sorting
    {
        return;                   // the array is sorted, so exit
    }
}
```

Comment: your generated random might be out of array bound
try first + (int)(Math.random()*(last-first) -1 )

Comment: Rohan - the error (using the sort on 10 numbers valued from 0-10, printing out the index values): Last: 9, first : 0
7
Last: 6, first : 0
3
Last: 2, first : 0
0
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)

ManZzup - I tried that, which makes the program run, but stop after a while with the array still unsorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you do

```
int pivot = first + random.nextInt(last-first+1)
```

you doesn't check if `last > first` before. So, you can be in the case where `last < first`, and try to call `random.nextInt()` with a negative (or zero) parameter, which doesn't makes sense, and so you will get and `IllegalArgumentException`.

What you have to do, is to move the pivot calculation inside your `if()`:

```
if (last - first >= 1){               // check that there are at least two elements to sort
    int pivot = first + random.nextInt(last-first+1);
```

Comment: Thanks, of course that has to be checked first.
I made the change, but it still won't sort for me. Here's the new numbers i get (the print for pivot inside the "if"-statement :
Last: 9, first : 0
Pivot:9
Last: 9, first : 10
Last: 8, first : 0
Pivot:7
Last: 8, first : 8
Last: 6, first : 0
Pivot:0
Last: 6, first : 7
Last: 5, first : 0
Pivot:0
Last: 5, first : 6
Last: 4, first : 0
Pivot:1
Last: 4, first : 2
Pivot:2
Last: 4, first : 3
Pivot:3
Last: 4, first : 4
Last: 2, first : 3
Last: 1, first : 2
Last: 0, first : 0

Answer (score -1):

```
int smth = (int)(Math.random()-1);
```